# Problems with threading

Tags: python, deadlock, multithreading

I got some problem with two threads which do seem to deadlock

The idea is this:

```
p1 = threading.Thread(targest  =myClass.setData, args = mylist)
p1.start()
p2 = threading.Thread(target = myClass.takeData, args = mylist)
p2.start()
```

mylist is a list.

Everything works absolutely fine when either the list is almost empty or when only either p1 or p2 is running.
If both run, they seem to deadlock.
I have tried to lock them - to no avail.

setData has an infinite while-loop which resets data in mylist, whereas takedata has an infinite whileloop which reads data from mylist.

Is it possible to do what I try to do?

Comment: Instead of describing your code in fairly vague terms, why not show us an actual runnable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Yeah it's possible. This is a common problem known as consumer-producer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Comment: use the module `queue`. `myClass.setData == queue.Queue.put` `myClass.takeData == queue.Queue.get`

Answer (score 1):

As [Adrián López](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959899/adrian-lopez)  says is a Producer-consumer problem. You have to use semaphores to lock the global data used by  `myClass.setData` and `myClass.takeData`.
Here you have a functional example to get ideas.

http://smherwig.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/producer-consumer-model-with-python.html